# How to resolve the following problem with DialogInput/PopupMenu?

Tags: bugs, mac-os-x, interface, dialog-window

Consider the following DialogInput:

```
di[list_,phrase_] := DialogInput[{choice = ""}, 
 Column[{TextCell[phrase], PopupMenu[Dynamic[choice], list], 
   Button["OK", DialogReturn[choice]]}]]
```

and some test list

```
list = Table[i,{i,1,50,1}];
```

When using

```
di[list,"Select:"]
```

I do not have any problem with Windows, but on MacOS Sonoma (and Mathematica 13.2), I have to maintain the click to select the list element, which can be a bit tricky on a trackpad; probably it is a bug related to Sonoma, but I am not sure. Could you please tell me whether you experience problems with `di`, and what is the analog of the `DialogInput`, which may not have the problem I described? Or at least any analog.

Comment: I do not see this issue on macOS big sur.  Definitely report to Wolfram Research